# Viewing temporary table from inside stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetTPICostCenters
IS
   varCost_Center VARCHAR2(10);
           varPI_MAX_DATE DATE;
           varFD_MAX_DATE DATE; 

BEGIN   

   --OPEN costcenter_WFDB;
   FOR item IN (select distinct(cost_center) as cost_center from fd_cost_center_validation where cost_center in 
           (select distinct(cost_center) from pi_cost_center_validation))
   LOOP
   --FETCH costcenter_WFDB INTO varCost_Center;



   SELECT GREATEST(nvl(CC_APPROVE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(CC_CHANGE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(CC_TAX_VALIDATE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01'),nvl(COST_POOL_DETER_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(DESC_UPDATE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01'),
   nvl(PRICING_METHOD_UPD_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(INTER_861_LAST_MODIFY_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01')) INTO varPI_MAX_DATE
   FROM pi_cost_center_validation WHERE COST_CENTER=item.cost_center;

   SELECT GREATEST(nvl(CC_APPROVE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(CC_CHANGE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(CC_TAX_VALIDATE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01'),nvl(COST_POOL_DETER_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(DESC_UPDATE_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01'),
   nvl(PRICING_METHOD_UPD_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01') ,nvl(INTER_861_LAST_MODIFY_DATE,DATE '0001-01-01')) INTO varFD_MAX_DATE
   FROM fd_cost_center_validation WHERE S_ROWID IN 
       (SELECT S_ROWID FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION FD GROUP BY COST_CENTER, S_ROWID
        HAVING S_ROWID = (SELECT MAX(S_ROWID) FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION WHERE COST_CENTER=FD.COST_CENTER))
        AND COST_CENTER=item.cost_center;

   IF (varPI_MAX_DATE>varFD_MAX_DATE) THEN   
    INSERT INTO TPI_Data
    (COST_CENTER,COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL,COST_POOL_PER,SUB_COST_POLL_SHORT_DESC,DRIVER,
     DRIVER_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING,COST_POOL_B,COST_POOL_B_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_B,
     DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2,COST_POOL_C,COST_POOL_C_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_C,DRIVER_3,DRIVER_3_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_3,MARKUP_BASE_3,PRICING_3,COST_POOL_D,
     COST_POOL_D_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_D,DRIVER_4,DRIVER_4_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_4,MARKUP_BASE_4,
     PRICING_4,COST_POOL_E,COST_POOL_E_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_E,DRIVER_5,DRIVER_5_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_5,
     MARKUP_BASE_5,PRICING_5     
    )
    SELECT COST_CENTER, COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL,COST_POOL_PER,
    SUB_COST_POLL_SHORT_DESC
    ,DRIVER,DRIVER_PER,
    MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING,COST_POOL_B,COST_POOL_B_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_B,DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,
    MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2,
    COST_POOL_C,COST_POOL_C_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_C,DRIVER_3,DRIVER_3_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_3,
    MARKUP_BASE_3,PRICING_3,
    COST_POOL_D,COST_POOL_D_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_D,DRIVER_4,DRIVER_4_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_4,
    MARKUP_BASE_4,PRICING_4,
    COST_POOL_E,COST_POOL_E_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_E,DRIVER_5,DRIVER_5_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_5,
    MARKUP_BASE_5,PRICING_5 FROM pi_cost_center_validation WHERE COST_CENTER=item.cost_center;   
   ELSE   
    INSERT INTO TPI_Data
    (COST_CENTER,COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL,COST_POOL_PER,SUB_COST_POLL_SHORT_DESC,DRIVER,
     DRIVER_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING,COST_POOL_B,COST_POOL_B_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_B,
     DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2,COST_POOL_C,COST_POOL_C_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_C,DRIVER_3,DRIVER_3_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_3,MARKUP_BASE_3,PRICING_3,COST_POOL_D,
     COST_POOL_D_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_D,DRIVER_4,DRIVER_4_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_4,MARKUP_BASE_4,
     PRICING_4,COST_POOL_E,COST_POOL_E_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_E,DRIVER_5,DRIVER_5_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_5,
     MARKUP_BASE_5,PRICING_5     
    )
     SELECT COST_CENTER, COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL,COST_POOL_PER,
     SUB_COST_POLL_SHORT_DESC,DRIVER,DRIVER_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING,COST_POOL_B,
     COST_POOL_B_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_B,DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2,
     COST_POOL_C,COST_POOL_C_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_C,DRIVER_3,DRIVER_3_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_3,MARKUP_BASE_3,PRICING_3,
     COST_POOL_D,COST_POOL_D_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_D,DRIVER_4,DRIVER_4_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_4,MARKUP_BASE_4,PRICING_4,
     COST_POOL_E,COST_POOL_E_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_E,DRIVER_5,DRIVER_5_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_5,MARKUP_BASE_5,PRICING_5 
     FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION WHERE S_ROWID IN 
       (SELECT S_ROWID FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION FD GROUP BY COST_CENTER, S_ROWID
        HAVING S_ROWID = (SELECT MAX(S_ROWID) FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION WHERE COST_CENTER=FD.COST_CENTER))
        AND COST_CENTER=item.cost_center;
     END IF;
    END LOOP;  
   --CLOSE costcenter_WFDB;

   INSERT INTO TPI_Data
    (COST_CENTER,COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL,COST_POOL_PER,SUB_COST_POLL_SHORT_DESC,DRIVER,
     DRIVER_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING,COST_POOL_B,COST_POOL_B_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_B,
     DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2,COST_POOL_C,COST_POOL_C_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_C,DRIVER_3,DRIVER_3_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_3,MARKUP_BASE_3,PRICING_3,COST_POOL_D,
     COST_POOL_D_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_D,DRIVER_4,DRIVER_4_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_4,MARKUP_BASE_4,
     PRICING_4,COST_POOL_E,COST_POOL_E_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_E,DRIVER_5,DRIVER_5_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_5,
     MARKUP_BASE_5,PRICING_5     
    )
     SELECT COST_CENTER, COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL,COST_POOL_PER,
     SUB_COST_POLL_SHORT_DESC,DRIVER,DRIVER_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING,COST_POOL_B,COST_POOL_B_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_B,DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2,COST_POOL_C,COST_POOL_C_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_C,DRIVER_3,DRIVER_3_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_3,MARKUP_BASE_3,PRICING_3,COST_POOL_D,COST_POOL_D_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_D,DRIVER_4,DRIVER_4_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_4,MARKUP_BASE_4,PRICING_4,COST_POOL_E,COST_POOL_E_PER,
     COST_SUB_POOL_E,DRIVER_5,DRIVER_5_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_5,MARKUP_BASE_5,PRICING_5 FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION 
     WHERE S_ROWID IN 
     (SELECT S_ROWID FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION FD GROUP BY COST_CENTER, S_ROWID
        HAVING S_ROWID = (SELECT MAX(S_ROWID) FROM FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION WHERE COST_CENTER=FD.COST_CENTER))
        AND COST_CENTER NOT IN (SELECT COST_CENTER FROM TPI_Data);


        COMMIT;

END;
```

In the above stored procedure TPI_Deata is the global temporary table which is getting populated in the procedure. In sql server we used to do "select * from temp_table" inside stored procedure to view the results when the stored procedure is executed but here what should I do with the global temporary table so that when I execute the stored procedure I get the set of records inside the table?

Comment: do a "select * from TPI_Data;" .. just don't do it INSIDE the procedure. Do it from whatever called the procedure.  Alternatively, you could have the procedure return a REF Cursor .. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#BABIIGAG

Comment: TPI_Data is temporary table, once the session is disconnected the rows are deleted from inside it. If I dont execute the stored procedure again before doing a "select* from TPI_Data" I will get empty table. Can you please help?

Comment: Wherever called this procedure, is still within the same session. Did you create the table with ON COMMIT PRESERVE?  or ON COMMIT DELETE ?  If you used the former, it'll be fine .. same session, no worries. If you did the latter, you might want to consider removing the commit from the procedure (some will argue COMMITs inside procedures are bad practice - I'm not going to argue that here, but it might be better for you not to if you used ON COMMIT DELETE) ;)

Comment: I used On Commit Preserve. But when user would be executing from front end it will be a new session and then only "select * from TPI_data" will get executed without the actual stored procedure. How can I make sure that the stored procedure is executed before the temp table is selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating temp table inside stored procedure in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409125/creating-temp-table-inside-stored-procedure-in-oracle)

Comment: Yeah, if you have a need to view the data in a different session, then global temp tables aren't your solution.  :)  Lalit's idea is probably a  good bet ...

Answer (score 1):

When using Oracle, you should forget about MSSQL. Their approaches are completely different. If you wish to return some tabular data from the stored procedure, you generally should use an out [REF CURSOR](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php) parameter. If you wish just to debug your data, then simple do SELECT after calling SP.

Bad news that in 12c Oracle realizes a [MSSQL-like facility](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1.php) for alleviation of ms-developers pain.

Comment: then again from front end i have to declare a ref_cursor type variable and then execute the stored procedure is it? I am trying to avoid to declare any further variable while execution, just a single execute procedure statement, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Sormita, if you got a tool you should understood it's preferred approaches. Now you looks like a biker who bought a Rolls-Royce and now trying to drive it on two wheels. From the front end.... Maybe you need no SP at all, just a single SELECT from this client side. But if you need to return resultset from SP, you should use ref cursor. At the server side you should describe sys_refcursor parameter into your SP. At the client side it depends of DAC. Google for ref cursor examples for your client library.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the table once the procedure is completed. If you are seeing zero rows, that is probably because the temporary table is declared with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` (which is the default) instead of `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2189569

If you are trying to view the results from a UI, you should either return a ref cursor or use regular tables, so that the data persists. In Global temporary tables, the data is gone once the session is closed.

Comment: that is what i want as the data that i am inserting in temporary table here is already present in 2 other tables, i dont want to create another table with the same data.

Comment: In that case, returning the ref cursor is the right way to go. Even the name GetTPICostCenters sort of indicates that the procedure/function returns a result set in the form of a ref cursor. (atleast that's the way I would understand it in an Oracle database context)